# Why my kivy app is automatically close when open?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to run a kivy app I made on windows. But when I launch the app the following message appear for half a second and close. Can someone help ?
[image]

Here is the original code that perfectly work.

```
import os, sys
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path, resource_find
import kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
kivy.require("2.1.0")

class Test(App):
    def build(self):

        def Button_Click(instance):
            lbl.text = "You clicked the button !"

        bx = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        btn = Button(text = "Click Me !")
        btn.bind(on_press = Button_Click)
        lbl = Label(color = "red")
        bx.add_widget(btn)
        bx.add_widget(lbl)

        return bx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    Test().run()
```

With another method, I also get an error :
*Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception maximum recursion depth exceeded*

I am sure that kivy is well installed.
I have also done it in a virtual environment.

Here is my .spec file:

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\loddo\\PycharmProjects\\TEST\\'),
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
```

My installed package :
[image]

Comment: Worked as expected. Make sure `kivy` is properly installed.

Comment: kivy.deps.gstreamer , kivy.deps.sdl2 and kivy.deps.glew are install